# accuracy in depth estimation monocular camera

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use a monocular SLR camera (industry level). I am planning to use this camera to find the orientation and position of certain objects in the image. The first step I performed was calibration of camera using OpenCV documentation. I have pasted a chessboard between a black sheet and glass (I have used glass instead of gluing the chessboard to sheet as it might warp the chessboard and glue also has its own thickness. I have placed this sheet at a 45 degree angle to camera (i.e. the top view of the experiment will have 45 degrees angle between the sheet and the camera). After detecting the chessboard corners using FindChessboardCorners function, I am using these points to solve for PnP as I already know the object points (World frame points with Z = 0), corners and Camera matrix plus distortion coefficients. I find the translation and rotation vector using this data with the function `cv::solvePnP(object_points, corners, Cam_Mat, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);`.
When I use the rvecs to find the Euler angles, I am getting a variation of 5 degreed. Any idea why this might be happening?

The code block is as follows:

```
cv::Vec3f rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(const cv::Mat& R) {
    
    float sy = std::sqrt(R.at<double>(0, 0) * R.at<double>(0, 0) + R.at<double>(1, 0) * R.at<double>(1, 0));

    bool singular = sy < 1e-6;

    float x, y, z;
    if (!singular) {
        y = std::atan2(-R.at<double>(2, 0), sy);
        x = std::atan2(R.at<double>(2, 1)/ std::cos(y), R.at<double>(2, 2) / std::cos(y));
        z = std::atan2(R.at<double>(1, 0) / std::cos(y), R.at<double>(0, 0) / std::cos(y));
    }
    else {
        cout << "singular!\n";
        y = std::atan2(-R.at<double>(2, 0), sy);
        x = std::atan2(-R.at<double>(1, 2), R.at<double>(1, 1));
        z = 0;
    }
    double pi = 3.14159;
    double x_deg = x * (180 / pi);
    double y_deg = y * (180 / pi);
    double z_deg = z * (180 / pi);


    cout << "Rx = " << x << "\nRy = "<< y <<"\nRz = " << z << endl;
    cout << "Rx degrees = " << x_deg << "\nRy Degrees = " << y_deg << "\nRz Degrees = " << z_deg << endl;

    return cv::Vec3f(x, y, z);
}

    class line_pose_estimator {
    public:
        line_pose_estimator(int height, int width, int square_dim) {
            board_height = height;
            board_width = width;
            squaresize = square_dim;
            patternsize = Size(board_width, board_height);
        }

        int board_height, board_width;
        Size patternsize;
        int squaresize;

        vector<Point2f> corners;
        vector<Point3f> object_points;

        const cv::TermCriteria criteria = cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 30, 0.01);
        const int chessboardflags = CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK;

        
        //input - grayscale image, 
        //output - translation and rotation vector of origin
        void find_origin(Mat image, string out_name, bool save_img = false) {
            string out_dir = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Pose Estimation\\Output Data\\";
            //camera intrinsic parameters
            Mat Cam_Mat = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);

            Cam_Mat.at<float>(0, 0) = 5.1863196755281979e+03;
            Cam_Mat.at<float>(1, 1) = 5.1863196755281979e+03;
            Cam_Mat.at<float>(0, 2) = 1.9195000000000000e+03;
            Cam_Mat.at<float>(2, 0) = 1.3735000000000000e+03;

            //distortion coefficients
            cv::Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
            distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = -2.2522257464640633e-01;
            distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = -3.3113981023075709e+00;
            distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = 0;
            distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = 0;
            distCoeffs.at<double>(4) = 1.5899309942518832e+02;

            //output vectors
            Mat rvecs(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
            Mat tvecs(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);

            //create object point containers with real world square size of chessboard
            for (int i = 0; i < board_height; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < board_width; ++j)
                    object_points.push_back(Point3f(j * squaresize, i * squaresize, 0));

            //find chessboard corners
            bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners(image, patternsize, corners);
            if (found) {
                std::cout << "Chessboard detected\n";
                cv::cornerSubPix(image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), criteria);
            }
            else {
                cout << "Chessboard not detected" << endl;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++) {
                cout << corners.at(i).x << ","<< corners.at(i).y << endl;
            }

            drawChessboardCorners(image, patternsize, Mat(corners), found);
            //projectPoints();
            if (save_img) {
                string output_filename = out_dir + out_name;
                cout << "-:" << output_filename << endl;
                cv::imwrite(output_filename, image);
            }
            if (found) {
                cv::solvePnP(object_points, corners, Cam_Mat, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

                cout << "Rvecs :\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < rvecs.rows; i++) {
                    cout << rvecs.at<double>(i, 0) << endl;
                }

                Mat Rot(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                cv::Rodrigues(rvecs, Rot, noArray());

                cout << "Rotation Mat 3X3 :\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        cout << Rot.at<double>(i, j) << ",";
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }

                cv::Vec3f EulerAngles = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Rot);

                cout << "Tvecs :\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < tvecs.rows; i++) {
                    cout << tvecs.at<double>(i, 0) << endl;
                }

            }
```

I assumed that the angles and translation data will be pretty accurate as I am using same points for calibration, but I am not getting a good enough validation of my code through physical measurements. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve better results?

Comment: your `Cam_Mat.at<float>(2, 0) = 1.3735000000000000e+03;` probably should instead be `Cam_Mat.at<float>(1, 2) = 1.3735000000000000e+03;` . What's your image resolution?

Comment: @Micka, it is 3840×2748

Comment: did you correct the intrinsic matrix (index (1,2) instead of (2,0))? Do you then get results that make more sense?

Comment: @Micka even after changing it, I am getting wrong answer. Now I am getting a rotation value in x as well. For a board that is perpendicular to the camera, my rvec is [-0.366, 0.518, 0.0006]. I am not sure why I am getting a rotation is x and y. Plus the z value is off by 30 mm than physical

Comment: did you verify that Cam_Mat and dist coefficients are identical to the calibration? During calibraion you also get tvec and rvec for each of the used images. Did you check them?

Comment: @Micka No I did not do that. How can I verify again? Also, if the chessboard is parallel to the camera, should it not give the rvec which will result in 0 Euler angle around Y axis? I am not getting that 0 degrees. Also how would you convert the rvec to Euler angles with respect to camera axes?

Comment: @Micka I verified the calibration extrinsics with a parallel chessboard image. that extrinsic is correct

Comment: And with the same image and same intrinsics you get a wrong object pose from solvePnp?

Comment: I am trying with different image

Comment: Would be an important test, whether same image that is ok in calibration gives good results or not. You even wrote "as I am using same points for calibration, but I am not getting a good enough validation of my code through physical measurements"

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote it wrong. But I did the calibration using different sets of inages. I am testing them on different chessboard images

Comment: can you show your calibration code? and the calibration result (e.g. printed to terminal with `std::cout << intrinsics << std::endl` and `for(auto it=dist.begin(); it != dist.end(); ++it) std::cout << *it << std::endl;` )?

Comment: @Micka the code is same as the opencv documentation code

Comment: You should print the result and copy it to your question text

Comment: @Micka , this is the stored K matrix in xml file when calibrated as per CV documentation     5.1863196755281979e+03 0. 1.9195000000000000e+03 0.
    5.1863196755281979e+03 1.3735000000000000e+03 0. 0. 1

Comment: Can you upload your test-image, the drawn detected  chessboard image and tell the printed results?

Comment: @Micka if it is possible,  we can correspond via email. I can share the data with you there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254208/discussion-between-dushyant-patil-and-micka).